# How to enable only one button as selectable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div where some set of divs will be populated dynamically.for that I have a button to select the particular row.Only one row should be selectable.
But right now all the rows are selectable when each button is clicked.
How can I restrict to only one button to be selected.

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="termRecords in $ctrl.quote.financeOption">
 <div class="col-lg-2 text-center" style="padding-top:.8%" ng-class="{'white-bg': !$ctrl.is{{termRecords.term}},'grey-bg': $ctrl.is{{termRecords.rateReference}}}">
                                    {{termRecords.totalAmountToRepay}} 
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-1 text-center" style="padding-top:.8%" ng-class="{'white-bg': !$ctrl.is{{termRecords.term}},'grey-bg': $ctrl.is{{termRecords.rateReference}}}">
       {{termRecords.equivalentAPR}} 
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-top:.3%">
    <button type="select" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="$ctrl.selectQuote(termRecords.rateReference)" selected>Select</button>
     </div>
```

```
this.selectQuote = function(selectedRow) {
  this.isQuoteSelected = true;
  angular.forEach(this.quote.financeOption, function(value, key) {
    if(selectedRow == value.term + "MonthsSelected") {

      _this.finance.totalAmountToRepay = value.totalAmountToRepay;
      _this.finance.equivalentAPR = value.equivalentAPR;
      _this.finance.totalPremium = value.totalPremium;
     } else {
        _this['is' + value.term + 'MonthsSelected'] = false;

     }
   });

};
```

I should make only one row selectable.If it is not clear please find the attached image.[image]

Comment: How do you determine which row is enabled?

Comment: Simply use radio button instead of select?

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic Mic It should be button.Cant use radio button

Comment: @Feathercrown there is another next button below this which will take us to next page after selecting one

Comment: @HVarma Okej, im not sure if its gonna work, but you can try this out:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){   
  $('.btn').prop('selected', false);        
  $(this).prop('selected', true);
  });
  });

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic I cant use jquery,I should be javascript or angular

Comment: @HVarma Ill try to explain you logic how i think it should be done. On each .btn click (or add class you want) first unselect all buttons with that class and after select just one that is clicked ^^ gl

Comment: when a button is clicked, the line is selected. At this moment, the others buttons need to be disabled?

Comment: function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.btn').disabled=true;
}
and add onclick="myFunction()" in <button> tag

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Not exactly disabled.If they want they can select 2nd button at that time first row shoukd not be highlighted or selected

Answer (score 0):

*** I apologize, just saw the comment of "I cant use JQuery", I will leave this in case it may help someone else. ***

Disclaimer 1: This is my first time trying to help answer a Question, so please be patient! :) I am happy to get any constructive feedback on how to better answer.

Disclaimer 2: It appears you are using Bootstrap. Is that correct? I have yet to learn Bootstrap, so forgive any errors I may bring in due to my current ignorance.

---

I just figured out how to do this on my own project and hope an answer here may help anyone else.

I have a class of "selected" that I apply to the button when a button is clicked. 
Using JQuery I "deselect" all buttons by removing the "selected" class and apply "selected" to the clicked button.

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {

  // Deselect all other buttons
  $('.btn').removeClass('selected');
  
  // Apply selected class
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```

If you have other buttons on the page you do not want deselected, then apply a specific class to the group of buttons that should only have one selected and remove the selected class from the group with an if statement. 
I applied a class of "quoteButton" for this example.
See below:

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
        
  // If a quoteButton is clicked, deselect all other departmentButtons
  if($(this).hasClass('quoteButton')) {
    $('.quoteButton').removeClass('selected');
  }

  // Apply selected class
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```

I hope that helps someone. I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.